Confusion on the procedure of public-key and private-key cryptography
Procedure: $1):$ choose two distinct primes $p$ and $q$.
$2):$ calculate $n=pq.$
$3):$ compute $\phi(n)=T$.
$4):$ get $E$ from $gcd(E,T)=1.$
$5):$ get $D$ from $ED \equiv 1 \pmod{T}$
To encrypt the message $M$, $M^E mod \ n=C$.
To decrypt the message $C$, $C^{D} mod \ n=M.$
After grading a difficult exam, a professor sends her marks to registry. She doesn’t want anyone meddling with the marks, so she adds a layer of security: a digital signature. This works as follows.
The professor has chosen two prime numbers $p$ and $q$, and computed $n = pq$ and $N =
\phi(n) = (p − 1)(q − 1)$. She chooses an $E, D ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ with $E · D ≡ 1 (mod N)$. She places the
public deciphering key $(n, D)$ on her website.
The professor sends a single number $m$ (the mark of the student) to registry. She then
appends, as a signature, the number $g = [m]^E
_n ∈ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} $ to the end of the mail. If registry
wants to verify that the mail is indeed sent by the professor, they can go to the webpage
of the professor and read the (public) deciphering key: $(n, D)$. The signature is validated if $[m]_n = g^D ∈ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$
$\textbf{Question:}$ Registry receives a score of $48$ and the digital signature $[9]_{143}$. They check the
professor’s website and find the public key: $(n, D) = (143, 13).$
Is the score correct, or has it been tampered with?
$\textbf{Attempt:}$ I think to check whether the information the score is correct or not,  just compute $C^{D} mod \ n$ and check whether it equals $48$ (i.e. $[9]^{13}_{143}=?[48]_{143}$). But the answer computes $[48]_{143}^{13}$, which seems to be $M^D$, but in the procedure, we do not need this. Where is my mistake here? Thanks in advance.

RSA cryptography doesn’t assess if a message has been tampered with or corrupted. It only encrypts a message so it can only be decrypted by the intended recipient. Is this a question coming from a book or homework assignment? Are you sure you’re reading it correctly?

@DFord I have added more information. It's a little bit long, thank you for your patience.

I see. This is an application of RSA that I’m not familiar with. But I found this after a quick Google search:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rsa-and-digital-signatures/

@DFord Anyway, I appreciate your advice.

You always compute $\text{sig}^\text{enc key}$ and see if that is the message/mark. The answer is wrong.  You should have $9^{13} = 113 \neq 48 \bmod 143$ so the message is forged. (It is weird that the public key is called $(n,D)$, but it doesn't matter as long as one is hidden.)

@Randall This problem assumes the following case: public decryption key, secret encryption key. In my lecture notes, it says that this case also has some useful applications.

Yeah, I know, it's just an unnecessarily confusing way to state it.  In RSA encryption, you have a private key $d$ and a public key $e$.  In RSA digital signatures, you can use the same keys:  $d$ private, $e$ public.  Why change it to $e$ private and $d$ public?  Not wrong, just weird and "asymmetric."

@Randall Get it, thank you!

My attempt is true, my teacher has corrected that mistake.
